# Get 'a' with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, proxy, cross-domain

Someone wrote me this piece of code a while ago for extracting a certain element(/data) of a website:

```
 $(function(){

   var site = 'http://www.telegraaf.nl'; 

   $.get('proxy.php', { site:site }, function(data){

      var href = $(data).find('h2').first().children(':first-child').prop('href');
      var url = href.split('/');
      href = href.replace(url[2], 'telegraaf.nl');


      $('.myDiv').html('<a href="' + href + '" target="_blank">' + href + '</a>');

   }, 'html');



});
```

It works well but not on this dutch news site: http://www.telegraaf.nl

Can someone explain to me why that is, what is so special about this website? What do I have to change to make it work?

Comment: What does proxy.php do? Does it alter the response body from telegraaf.nl in any way?

Comment: @Michael Bird I think it's addressing php which I have on my server http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/ I don't think it does anything to alter response of body

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because they use jQuery on telegraaf.nl too.

Have a look at the answers here: [jQuery dialog over content from another site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109596/jquery-dialog-over-content-from-another-site) where someone experienced a similar problem. Guy mograbi's answer is very detailed and explains a lot.