# How to use an event listener like windows.onload or a.click more than once on same page?

Tags: javascript, event-listener, onload

I have some external js scripts that I offer to my users to be embedded on their site. Individually they work fine, but if you try to append two in the same page one of them crash (no error on console). I think the problem have to be with calling windows.onload several times.

Here how two embedded codes looks like:

### Code 1

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/widget.js"></script>
  <p><span class="punctis-social-widget"></span></p>
```

### Code 2

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/poll.js"></script>
  <p><span class="punctis-poll-button"></span></p>
```

poll.js and widget.js are just two simple functions:

**poll.js**

```
window.onload = function() {
   alert('IM POLL.js');
}
```

**widget.js**

```
window.onload = function() {
   alert('IM WIDGET.js');
}
```

One of this script will not load if you insert code 1 and code 2 in the same page. How can i solve this?

Comment: Like so: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: here's an answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558325/adding-multiple-onload-handlers

Answer (score 2):

Use **[EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**

You cannot have two window.onload on same page.
the second one will override first one. To solve your problem use multiple `addEventListener` instead. It will add the functionality instead of replacing the same.

Just replace this `window.onload=function(){}`

by this `window.addEventListener("load", function(evt) { /* do something */ })`

Explanation:

```
let el = document.getElementById('a'); // window in your case

el.addEventListener('click', function(evt) { /* do task 1 */ });
el.addEventListener('click', function(evt) { /* do task 2 */ });

//similarily for window
window.addEventListener("load", function(evt) { /* do task 1 */})
window.addEventListener("load", function(evt) { /* do task 2 */})
```